# Getting compilation errors in Catalyst framework in Ubuntu

Tags: perl, catalyst

I am building an application on Catalyst framework and I am a complete novice at it. Yesterday I installed SQLite and since then I am getting error messages like:

```
mohit@mohit-Studio-1555:~$ catalyst.pl
Undefined subroutine &Catalyst::Exception::Base::with called at /usr/share/perl5/Catalyst/Exception.pm line 50.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/Catalyst/Utils.pm line 4.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/Catalyst/Utils.pm line 4.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/Catalyst/Helper.pm line 12.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/Catalyst/Helper.pm line 12.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/bin/catalyst.pl line 26.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/bin/catalyst.pl line 26.
```

I tried reinstalling, cleaning and tried to google it but unable to resolve.

Please help me out. What can be the problem?

---

After upgrading `namespace::clean` I get this error:

```
The old Moose::Util::MetaRole API (before version 0.94) has been deprecated at /usr/share/perl5/Catalyst/Exception/Basic.pm line 3
Catalyst::Exception::Basic::BEGIN() called at /usr/lib/perl5/MooseX/Role/WithOverloading.pm line 3
eval {...} called at /usr/lib/perl5/MooseX/Role/WithOverloading.pm line 3
require Catalyst/Exception/Basic.pm called at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1/Class/MOP.pm line 114
Class::MOP::__ANON__() called at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/Try/Tiny.pm line 71
eval {...} called at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/Try/Tiny.pm line 67
Try::Tiny::try('CODE(0x8f366b8)', 'Try::Tiny::Catch=REF(0x8e6b9c8)') called at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1/Class/MOP.pm line 125
Class::MOP::load_first_existing_class('Catalyst::Exception::Basic') called at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1/Class/MOP.pm line 137
Class::MOP::load_class('Catalyst::Exception::Basic', undef) called at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1/Moose/Util.pm line 113
Moose::Util::_apply_all_roles('Moose::Meta::Class=HASH(0x8f36458)', undef, 'Catalyst::Exception::Basic') called at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1/Moose/Util.pm line 91
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you installed a version of [Package::Stash](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Package%3a%3aStash) which breaks your installed version of [namespace::clean](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/namespace%3a%3aclean) and didn't catch the conflict warning. Upgrading namespace::clean to the newest version should resolve your problems.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I got a new problem after upgrading.

Comment: That's not an error, it's a warning, and you should ask a new question if you have a new question -- but upgrade MooseX::Role::WithOverloading.